# How to push data to an two-level nested array in mongo db based on nested array id?

Tags: mongodb

I am working with applications using MongoDB, nodeJs. I have a document with 2 level nested data on it. I want to push data of a 2-level nested array based on a 1-level "uuid". I will attach my document picture and you will know exactly what I wanted.

[image]

Node code:

```
await collection.update(
{
 uuid: req.query.sub_uuid
},
{
 $push: { subtests.uuid: req.body }
});
await test.save();
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use  [$arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) that you can put some constraint on your update element inside the array.

```js
db.collections.updateMany({
  "subtests.uuid": 'your_uuid'
},
{
  $set: {
    { $push: { "subtests.$[el].subtrests": { /*item you want to push in the array */ } } }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "el.uuid": 'your_uuid'
    }
  ]
})
```

with this approach, you can update only the element who have your uuid.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer...But @Ashkan Actually I am using mongoose on my backend and I trying to execute this query but I am getting "CallBack.apply is not a function" error from my mongoose.....I search for array filtering in mongoose docs but I didn't found what I am looking for...Your understand my solution!.... You know how to do it in mongoose let me know....Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not an expert in mongoose, mostly use waterline in the projects.  But the point is, whenever I want to do some complex queries like this one, use row query. Writing complex queries with ORMs is hard to write, read, and also hard to update. @RehanShah